# File bigger than 2MB fails to upload on Nova 2 while using Laravel Vapor

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-vapor

Works fine on local host, but not on Laravel Nova. The error is so generic as below.

Initially I thought its the timeout on Vapor, so I set it to 60 seconds, but the error still persists.

`The document file failed to upload.` No error logs whatsoever.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, I just setup a normal file uploading facility within my normal webapp (outside of nova)

Comment: @AliGajani Have you found a solution ? Any updated ?

Comment: I ended up using Laravel vapor signed uploads process

Answer (score -1):

It's PHP problem
once you increase these values in `php.ini` you are good to go.

```
memory_limit
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

you may need to restart apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Sorry but @Ali Gajani is asking for the LARAVEL-VAPOR this totally difference thing if don't know. Please re-search about this.

Comment: Vapor is a serverless environment. This is impossible on Vapor